# splatting an array inside a string

Tags: ruby

Starting from and array of numbers such as

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

I need to get the following string

```
"values in (1,2,3)"
```

If I try a simple interpolation

```
"values in (#{a})"  => "values in ([1,2,3])"
```

I could use gsub to remove [ and ] but I'd rather find a cleaner way. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one more :

```
a = [1,2,3]
p "values in (#{a* ","})" # => "values in (1,2,3)"
```

Comment: Thanks, this one looks even better to me.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
"values in (#{a.join(",")})"
```

Comment: definitely better than gsub. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
a, bracs = [1,2,3], %w{[] ()}

p "values in #{a}".tr(*bracs) #=> "values in (1, 2, 3)"
```